# HP iLO Powershell Management: Send Key while in Boot Menu

Tags: powershell, hp, deployment, ilo

Scenario: I try to automate Windows Deployments on HP Gx Servers with the powershell management for iLO. I managed to start & stop a server, insert a disc and change the boot priority. It all works fine.

The Problem: The changed boot priority brings me to the point where i have to "press any key" to boot from the cd. Otherwise it the boot of the pre installed os on the hdd will continue.

[Screenshot: Press any key to boot from cd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbzc9.gif)

Now i am searching for a solution to boot directly into the virtual media disc. For example invoke a keypress with powershell or simulate it.

Another approach would be to "disable" or remove the hdd (with the existing os) temporary so there would be no other boot options but the virtual cdrom..

Answer (score 0):

Look into the ILO boot_once and boot_always commands.

From the shell, I usually set `vm cdrom set boot_once` for an OS installation.

Comment: I did that with:     
`Set-HPiLOVMStatus -Server $iloIP -Username $usr -Password $pass -VMBootOption BOOT_ONCE -Device CDROM`
Also i tried `VMBootOption CONNECT` , but still it still asks me to press any key.